# Gradle sync failed: Could not initialize class org.gradle.internal.classloader.FilteringClassLoader (115 ms)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I open the project in android studio, the compiler prompts Gradle sync failed: Could not initialize class org. Gradle. Internal. This. FilteringClassLoader (115 ms), and can't find any solution, please help me

I tried to delete all the configuration and download it again, but it didn't work, also I executing a new project showed the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is a Chinese path, I also encountered this error, is the idea crack file has a Chinese path